# How can I add click handler with kendo chart category axis with angular 2

Tags: angular, event-handling, kendo-chart

I am using **kendo chart** in an **angular 2** project and tried to add a link for the `kendo-chart-category-axis-item` text but it did not work. Is there away to add a link to it or at least to add a **click** event handler to it instead?

```
<kendo-chart-category-axis>
   <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="Date">
   </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
</kendo-chart-category-axis>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it is now available to use "**axisLabelClick**" in kendo chart tag, and you can add the label to the axis like below:

```
<kendo-chart (axisLabelClick)="axisLabelClickHandler($event)">
   <kendo-chart-category-axis>
      <kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
         <kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels [content]="Date"> </kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels>
      </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
   </kendo-chart-category-axis>
</kendo-chart>
```